# ListView to display news?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an app that displays news like Facebook. I researched and decided to build a fragment that parse html from a specific website and shows a picture and a description.

My Main Activity would be a `LinearLayout` that displays fragments as lists. How can i reuse that same fragment for multiple news posts?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `ListView` and an `ArrayAdapter<News>` for storing "headlines" of a `News` object instead of a `LinearLayout`. Then, generally speaking, the approach for showing an "article" goes like this.

1. Make a `News` class
2. Recommended: Have it `implements Parcelable` and write the code necessary to do that
3. Implement a `static NewsFragment newInstance(New news)` method of the Fragment class
4. Run something like so

   ```
   News n = new News();
   NewsFragment newsFrag = NewsFragment.newInstance(n);
   getFragmentManager().beginTransation().replace(R.id.container, newsFrag).commit();
   ```

Much of this is covered in [**Building a Flexible UI**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Alternatively, if you want a NewsFeed type layout, that is at [**Lists and Cards**](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Most important takeaway, you shouldn't use a LinearLayout for scrolling content.